# Auto-focus the cursor when pasting a link for another duplicate when clicking the "Add" button

Tags: feature-request, duplicate-questions

**Edit:**

I noticed today when I wanted to add another reference link for a duplicate question, that auto-focusing seems to have been implemented, which is nice.

Did my feature request have anything to do with this, or was this something that was (already) in the works before my original post?

---

Original post:

Often times, I find myself *(and possibly others that have the privilege to add more duplicates)* to use more than one duplicate for a question that requires a few duplicates to solve a question and having to click inside the input area for each additional duplicate.

Wouldn't it make sense if the cursor was already focused in the input as soon as you click the "Add" button; wasn't that what it was meant for, or am I wrong?

**Special relevant note:** The thing is; the cursor (already) auto-focuses in the input for a standard vote to close as a (first initial) duplicate, so why would it be different when adding additional duplicates?

*Yet,* how does the list of other posts that show up below the input know that one *(or more)* of those fits the bill? Maybe none do and it happens (to me) often that none do and that's where a known direct link taken from a Google search is pasted in and that's my post is about.

Most of the time, questions that appear in a list in the modal do not address the additional duplicate(s) required to show the OP how they can fix their code.

If this isn't feasible, is there a (particular) reason as to why it shouldn't work that way?

[image]